# Pass fixed variable from route to controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to pass a variable through my route to my controller, but I have multiple routes (categories) leading to the same controller i.e.

```
Route::get('/category1/{region}/{suburb?}', 'SearchController@search');
Route::get('/category2/{region}/{suburb?}', 'SearchController@search');
```

Making /category1, 2, etc. to be a parameter /{category} is not an option and I don't want to make separate controller function for each category.

How do I send the first segment of the url to my search controller? i.e. category1 or category2?

At present controller is as follows:

```
public function search($region, $suburb = null) { }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain why "making /category1, 2, etc. to be a parameter /{category} is not an option" ?

Comment: Just due to the fact that I'll have these folder names with other pages associated to them like /category1/about, /category1/tips-for-blaa. As thats the first directory too after the main URL everything would try to use that route?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use {category} as parameter. It's not possible to give information to a controller within a `Route::get` without modifing `laravel/framework` code.

Comment: Won't that mean that any url i.e. www.a.com/var1/var2/var3 would always trigger that controller though...? Perhaps I need to create individual controllers which just all call a single function? Or 404 anything that comes in that isn't appropriate through my SearchController@search function

Comment: I don't get it. If you want to show /category1/about, what you need to do is create a view that resides in resources folder (assuming you are using Laravel 5); why bother to create folders in document/application root to save those htmls/views? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Say I have a url site.com/hairdresser/california which runs a search on hairdressers in california. But then I might have site.com/hairdresser/how-to-cut-hair. So I can make the seperate route for that. but then any url type into my site site.com/bogus/value would load my /{cat}/{reg} route. which I don't want. If this is the only way that's cool, I'll just run some error checking on that function to hit a 404 page if someone types in some bogus url - if this is appropriate that's what I'll do I just don't have the experience to answer that sorry. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify a mask for your {category} parameter so that it must fit the format "category[0-9]+" in order to match the route.

```
Route::get('/{category}/{region}/{suburb?}', 'SearchController@search')
    ->where('category', 'category[0-9]+');
```

Now, your example url (from the comments) `www.a.com/var1/var2/var3` will only match the route if `var1` matches the given category regex.

More information can be found in the documentation for route parameters [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters).

### Edit

Yes, this can work with an array of string values. It is a regex, so you just need to put your array of string values into that context:

```
Route::get('/{category}/{region}/{suburb?}', 'SearchController@search')
    ->where('category', 'hairdresser|cooper|fletcher');
```

Or, if you have the array built somewhere else:

```
$arr = ['hairdresser', 'cooper', 'fletcher'];

// run each array entry through preg_quote and then glue
// the resulting array together with pipes
Route::get('/{category}/{region}/{suburb?}', 'SearchController@search')
    ->where('category', implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $arr)));
```

### Edit 2 (solutions for original request)

Your original question was how to pass the hardcoded category segment into the controller. If, for some reason, you didn't wish to use the solution above, you have two other options.

**Option 1:** don't pass the value in, just access the segments of the request in the controller.

```
public function search($region, $suburb = null) {
    $category = \Request::segment(1);
    dd($category);
}
```

**Option 2:** modify the route parameters using a before filter (L4) or before middleware (L5).

Before filters (and middleware) have access to the route object, and can use the methods on the route object to modify the route parameters. These route parameters are eventually passed into the controller action. The route parameters are stored as an associative array, so that needs to be kept in mind when trying to get the order correct.

If using Laravel 4, you'd need a before filter. Define the routes to use the before filter and pass in the hardcoded value to be added onto the parameters.

```
Route::get('/hairdresser/{region}/{suburb?}', ['before' => 'shiftParameter:hairdresser', 'uses' => 'SearchController@search']);
Route::get('/cooper/{region}/{suburb?}', ['before' => 'shiftParameter:cooper', 'uses' => 'SearchController@search']);
Route::get('/fletcher/{region}/{suburb?}', ['before' => 'shiftParameter:fletcher', 'uses' => 'SearchController@search']);

Route::filter('shiftParameter', function ($route, $request, $value) {
    // save off the current route parameters    
    $parameters = $route->parameters();
    // unset the current route parameters
    foreach($parameters as $name => $parameter) {
        $route->forgetParameter($name);
    }

    // union the new parameters and the old parameters
    $parameters = ['customParameter0' => $value] + $parameters;
    // loop through the new set of parameters to add them to the route
    foreach($parameters as $name => $parameter) {
        $route->setParameter($name, $parameter);
    }
});
```

If using Laravel 5, you'd need to define a new before middleware. Add the new class to the app/Http/Middleware directory and register it in the `$routeMiddleware` variable in app/Http/Kernel.php. The logic is basically the same, with an extra hoop to go through in order to pass parameters to the middleware.

```
// the 'parameters' key is a custom key we're using to pass the data to the middleware
Route::get('/hairdresser/{region}/{suburb?}', ['middleware' => 'shiftParameter', 'parameters' => ['hairdresser'], 'uses' => 'SearchController@search']);
Route::get('/cooper/{region}/{suburb?}', ['middleware' => 'shiftParameter', 'parameters' => ['cooper'], 'uses' => 'SearchController@search']);
Route::get('/fletcher/{region}/{suburb?}', ['middleware' => 'shiftParameter', 'parameters' => ['fletcher'], 'uses' => 'SearchController@search']);

// middleware class to go in app/Http/Middleware
// generate with "php artisan make:middleware" statement and copy logic below
class ShiftParameterMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        // get the route from the request
        $route = $request->route();

        // save off the current route parameters
        $parameters = $route->parameters();
        // unset the current route parameters
        foreach ($parameters as $name => $parameter) {
            $route->forgetParameter($name);
        }

        // build the new parameters to shift onto the array
        // from the data passed to the middleware
        $newParameters = [];
        foreach ($this->getParameters($request) as $key => $value) {
            $newParameters['customParameter' . $key] = $value;
        }

        // union the new parameters and the old parameters
        $parameters = $newParameters + $parameters;
        // loop through the new set of parameters to add them to the route
        foreach ($parameters as $name => $parameter) {
            $route->setParameter($name, $parameter);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the data from the custom 'parameters' key added
     * on the route definition.
     */
    protected function getParameters($request) {
        $actions = $request->route()->getAction();
        return $actions['parameters'];
    }
}
```

Now, with the filter (or middleware) setup and in use, the category will be passed into the controller method as the first parameter.

```
public function search($category, $region, $suburb = null) {
    dd($category);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting - I'd want to swap the 'category[0-9]+' for an array of string values? Is this somehow possible, it doesn't appear to be in the documentation?

Comment: @patricus is right. it will work. for more info http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: Can it work with an array of string values? I can't see where it does. In which case if I have Route::get('/{category}/{region}/{suburb?}', 'SearchController@search'); then I have something like Route::get('/this/isa/normallink, 'AnotherController@getIndex'); this link doesn't work it goes to the /{}/{}/{} route (SearchController). This was the issue I thought I would have hence the /{category} was not an option. The above may work if it works for strings, not numbers. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @sprintcar78a I have updated the answer in regards to your array of strings.

Comment: @sprintcar78a Glad it helped. I have added some additional solutions you may find interesting, but the current solution should work just fine. Plenty of ways to get stuff done in Laravel!

Comment: Came across the segment part on Google prior to asking the question but got an error. it didn't say to put a \ before it - so it now works! I think the Segment approach is probably the "easiest"/"clearest" for me to use :) I appreciate your time and effort, thank you again.

Comment: @sprintcar78a If your class is in a namespace, you either need to add a `use Request;` statement at the top of the file (after the namespace, before the class), or use the fully qualified class name (which, in this case, is \Request, since the Request facade is in the global namespace).

Comment: I can't believe it's impossible to just deliver a static key-value pair from route definition to controller without writing a mini-library for the purpose.