# What is the easiest way to pass a variable from Route to Controller in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel

This might be super simple but I'm asking because I'm new to this.

I have a View named 'defaultpage' , I have two routes and one controller as below.

`Route::get('about', 'PageController@showPage');`

```
Route::get('welcome', 'PageController@showPage');
```

.

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public  function showPage(){

        return view('defaultpage', compact('var'));
    }
}
```

I want to pass a variable named $var from above routes to below controller , If $var is coming from 'about' route , $var should be equal to a value given in about route and the controller will pass it to the view , and same with the 'welcome' route.

How can I do this . Any help will be appreciated . Thank you .

Comment: try changing your function to look like this `public  function showPage($var)`

Comment: done. but how to pass $var from route to the function  @WdyDev

Comment: where $var is comming from ?? is user inserting that value ?

Comment: no. $var is hard coded in to route

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass fixed variable from route to controller in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933834/pass-fixed-variable-from-route-to-controller-in-laravel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to pass variable from route to controller if the varible is coming from view is to put it a link as below

```
<a href="/myRoute/{{ $variableName }}">Click me</a>
```

In routes:

```
Route::get('myRoute/{variable}', 'ControllerName@getFunction');
```

In Controller

```
public function getFunction($variable){
  echo $variable;
}
```

Comment: thanks , but how can I hardcode the $var in to route and do this ?